# If $f: R \to R$ is one one and differentiable function and graph of $y = f(x)$ is symmetrical about the point $(4,0)$ then...

Tags: calculus

If $f: R \to R$ is one one and differentiable function and graph of $y = f(x)$ is symmetrical about the point $(4,0)$ then, 
If $f'(-100) >0$ then roots of $x^{2} - f'(10)x - f'(10) = 0$ may be non real.  (True/false)

My attempt:
First, it is given that $f(4+x) = -f(4-x)$
So, $f'(4+x) = f'(4-x)$
 Also discriminant for the given equation is, $(f'(10))^{2} +4f'(10)$

Now, I don't know how to utilize the given information.
Any hint would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is injective and defined on whole real line, it follows that it is either non-increasing or non-decreasing on the whole domain, where it is not constant in an interval. $f'(-100)>0$ says that the function is non-decreasing. Therefore, $f'(10)\geq 0$ and the discriminant is non-negative. Hence, the answer is **false**.

Note that symmetry about $(4,0)$ is not required.

Hope it helps:)

Comment: Can I say that since $f$ is injective and defined on whole real line, then it is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing$?$

Comment: Yes, you can say that. But it is safe to say the non-increasing and non-decreasing case, where the function is not constant in an interval, to avoid situations like $x^3$ at $x=0$.